# What happens if i don't use zero-based array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Can someone explain what would happen? Is it really necessary to start at index `0` instead of `1` (which would be easier for me)?

Comment: You will eventually run into trouble with any library function using arrays (e.g. string library) and dynamically allocated arrays (for the size).

Comment: What usually happens is that the software gets very confused and screws up.  The last 'I like to start my arrays at 1' question I saw on SO had, (surprise), obi wan errors:(

Comment: If your array is defined as e.g. `int array[1]` and you access it as `array[1]`, then you can expect [nasal demons demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: Not true! Last time I had UB my computer asked me about a pizza.

Comment: Reminds me - I have no extra pepperoni left:(

Comment: @Olaf Sir,... did it ask for any specific toppings, too? Mine did. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Beetle-juice (3 times) and [crunchy frogs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dy6uLfermPU).

Comment: You would probably find it difficult getting a programming job.

Comment: It will be much easier to adopt counting from zero than make any code cope with counting from one. Elegant code would be impossible. Trust me, I'm a doctor.

Comment: If you want 1-based indexing, I would recommend Ada or Pascal. Wirth dropped that with Modula (and he did not drop a feature easily if he saw any value in it). With these languages you can even start your indexes whereever you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can do whatever you want, as long as your array subscript is strictly less than the size of the array.

Example:

```
int a[100];

a[1] = 2;   // fine, 1 < 100
```

Comment: Problem is he will likely run into trouble for allocation if not caring about the  (unused) zero-index.

Comment: @Olaf: No, why? There's no indication that that should be about to happen.

Comment: `int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); // 10 elements: index 1..10` ? That becomes more nasty for multiple dimensions. However, regarding the question itself, the OP might likely run into trouble much earlier before he cares about `malloc`&friends.

Comment: @Olaf: Well, as I did try to say in my post (but perhaps not clearly enough), the subscript has to be strictly less than the size.

Answer (score 5):

> *What happens if I don't use zero-based array in C*

Well, you **can't**. `C` arrays are zero based, by definition, by standard.

> *Is it really necessary to start at 0?*

Well, this is no rule to **prevent** you from leaving index `0` *unused*, but then, you'll almost certainly not get the desired result.

Comment: Yes, there I got a true admirer of my answer!!! Dear sir/Madam, please state the reason for the downvote, I'm interested. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using non-zero based arrays in `C` is possible, but not recommended. Here is how you would allocate a 1-based array of 100 integers:

```
int * a = ((int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int)))-1;
```

The `-1` moves the start of the pointer back one from the start of the array, making the first valid index 1. So this array will have valid indices from 1 to 100 inclusive.

```
a[1]   = 10; /* Fine */
a[100] = 7;  /* Also fine */
a[0]   = 5;  /* Error */
```

The reason why this isn't recommended is that everything else in `C` assumes that pointers to blocks of memory point to the first element of interest, not one before that. For example, the array above won't work with `memcpy` unless you add 1 to the pointer when passing it in every time.

Comment: That code is illegitimate, since it creates a pointer which points neither to something allocated storage, nor to the "just-beyond" spot.  Creation of such pointers is Undefined Behavior, regardless of whether or not they are referenced; a compiler could (from the standpoint of the C Standard) perfectly legitimately replace the `int *a = ...` statement with code that seeks out and destroys all Justin Bieber recordings, since there is no circumstance in which the behavior of that statement would be defined.

Comment: That is another reason to avoid it, then. With that said, though, it will be quite a feat to track down a compiler where this doesn't work. While all undefined behavior is the same according to the standard, in practice some is much more benign than others. This case is among the safest kinds of undefined behavior possible.

Comment: It would be helpful if the Standard were to describe more forms of normative behavior beyond the required ones, and required implementations to define feature macros similar to FLT_EVAL_METHOD which code could validate to ensure that it would only be used on platforms that supported the expected behaviors, but as yet it doesn't.  Some compiler authors have taken the view that in the interest of optimizing performance for inputs that do not cause Undefined Behavior to occur, compilers should assume that no combination of inputs that would cause Undefined Behavior to occur will ever be received.

Comment: Since compiler writers espousing that philosophy have not been exiled from polite society, there can be no "safe" Undefined Behavior for any code which might be processed using a compiler written by such a person.  Static analysis could very quickly determine that any code which reached that `malloc` statement would invoke Undefined Behavior whether `malloc` returned `null` or not; if the compiler can determine that calling method `foo` will always invoke Undefined Behavior, a compiler may replace `if (x > 0) bar(); else foo();` with an unconditional call to `bar`.

Comment: Yes, that could potentially happen. I don't think you'll find one that actually does that, though. Standards are very important, but what compilers actually do should not be neglected. Codifying existing practice is an important part of standards writing.

Comment: Some of the authors involved with LLVM have blogged about their efforts to make their compilers aggressively prune code which would only be relevant for inputs that do not cause UB; some security bugs have made their way into production code as a result of such pruning, so the danger is not theoretical.  I agree 100% that codifying existing practice is an important part of standards writing, but the maintainers of the C Language Standard seem oblivious to practices which have been nearly-universally supported.  I know of any two's-complement-platform compiler released before 2010 where...

Comment: ... given `int32_t x,y;`, the expression `x << y;` would not yield the same result as `x * ((int32_t)1 << y);` in cases where the latter was defined, though I do know of some where the former expression would evaluate much more quickly.  I would posit that existing practice strongly favors having `x << y` be equivalent to `x * ((TYPE_OF_X)1 << y)` [especially since the latter is only equivalent if the type of `x` is correctly specified] but the Standard's Committee has chosen not to hold compilers--even those for two's-complement platforms--to that tradition.